# Правописание падежных окончаний

Tags: грамматика

У нас в Азербайджане денежная единица "манат". Насколько я знаю, что при числительных пять и выше существительные ставятся в родительном падеже множественнго числа. Существительное "манат" мужского рода с твёрдой основой. Оно  в род. падеже множественного числа по правилам должно иметь  окончание -ов. А в газетах я повстречал форму типа "сто манат".Как можно правильно сказать, например: "пять, шесть, сто... манат или же манатов?.

Answer (score 1):

Основной формой для сущ. с твердой основой в форме Р.п. мн.ч. является окончание ОВ, но также в частных тематических случаях  используется нулевое окончание (пять англичан, пара ботинок, пять ампер, пять килограмм/килограммов). При наличии двух форм окончание ОВ является нейтральным или книжным, а нулевое - разговорным.

Соответственно, основной формой для денежной единицы "манат" является окончание ОВ, например: "Самая крупная банкнота – 100 манатов – представляет собой символику экономического прогресса: силуэты древних строений, постройки середины XX века и современные здания из стекла и бетона, сменяющие друг друга слева направо".http://www.banki.ru/products/currency/azn/

Тем не менее, в тестах встречается нулевое окончание, которое можно считать разговорным.